# компилирую проект используя maven, tomcat8, mysql. и получаю ошибку, если я правильно понимаю ошибка где-то при подключении к бд

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

```
db.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lookingforfellowtravelerbelaruswebapi
db.username = root
db.password = root
db.entity.package = by.andreiblinets.entity

db.initialSize = 30
db.minIdle = 30
db.maxIdle = 90
db.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 30000
db.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
db.testOnBorrow = true
db.validationQuery = select version()
The detailed error is given below :

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [by/andreiblinets/config/DatabaseConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4768)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5236)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1730)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:287)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:432)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:287)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1408)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:877)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:805)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Unable to open JDBC connection for schema management target
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.TargetDatabaseImpl.prepare(TargetDatabaseImpl.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:481)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:802)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2294)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2039)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1533)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.TargetDatabaseImpl.prepare(TargetDatabaseImpl.java:38)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:984)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:910)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3923)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1273)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2031)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:718)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:302)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:282)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:39)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:256)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2304)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2290)
    ... 75 more
```

Comment: `Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client`

Answer (score 0):

А конфиги прописаны корректно?
Проверьте следующий вариант:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lookingforfellowtravelerbelaruswebapi?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&characterSetResults=UTF-8
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
#spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.platform=mysql
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```